# How to call a function inside another function in Go language?

Tags: function, go, struct, boolean

I'm getting an error saying "undefined isvalid". How do I call another function in a function?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Position struct {
    row int
    col int
}

func (posstn Position) isvalid() bool {
    if posstn.row > 8 || posstn.row < 0 || posstn.col > 8 || posstn.col < 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func Possmov(pos Position) {
    var isval isvalid
    if isval == true {
        fmt.Println("Something")
    }
}

func main() {
    Possmov(Position{1, 7})
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could take the Tour of Go https://tour.golang.org once more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may call `isvalid()` like this `pos.isvalid()` see this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Position struct {
    row int
    col int
}

func (posstn Position) isvalid() bool {
    if posstn.row > 8 || posstn.row < 0 || posstn.col > 8 || posstn.col < 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func Possmov(pos Position) {
    isval := pos.isvalid()
    if isval == true {
        fmt.Println("Something")
    }
}
func main() {
    Possmov(Position{1, 7}) //Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line in function `Possmov(pos Position){...}` i.e. `var isval isvalid` is actually attempting to declare a variable of type `isvalid` (which is undefined as described by the error)

Instead your `isvalid()` method is declared on the `Position` type.

Try: `var isvalid = pos.isvalid()` in it's place

Answer (score 0):

Your defined `var isval isvalid`, while `isvalid` is not a known type in Go, instead:

```
func Possmov(pos Position) {

    var isval bool  // default is false

    if isval == true {

        fmt.Println("Something")

    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ml2PgEOZfV